# wikipedia page to category mapping database

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia, wikimedia-dumps

I was looking for a database which can help me in getting a list of all the categories a page belongs to, or all the pages present in a category. It is not there is the page enwiki-latest-page.sql databse and I am trying to avoid using the 42 GB xml dump. Is there some database available online which can help me in this regard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `page` dump contains information from [the `page` table](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aPage_table). The information you're looking for is in [the `categorylinks` table](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aCategorylinks_table), so you will also need the `categorylinks` dump.

Comment: @BhavyaAgarwal Yeah, category hierarchies are in `categorylinks` too, but category hierarchies are just a special case of category membership.